# How to output inline text with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added a !important to make sure that my css rules comes first but my inputs still behave like it was display in block; [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/zNFD4/3/)

```
input{
    display: inline!important;
  }

<p>My name is 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" style='display:inline;'/>
from USA. And I'm     <input type="text" placeholder="21" class="form-control" style='display:inline;'/> years old.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is reset the width to `auto` - it was `100%`. It's worth noting that the Bootstrap styling is coming from the `.form-control` selector; use that to overwrite it.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6QGt3/)

```
.form-control {
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

No need for inline styling or `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>My name is 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control"  style='display:inline; width:100px'/>
from USA. And I'm     <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="21" class="form-control" style='display:inline; width:100px'/> years old.
</p>
```

you can resize your input button with CSS including width in input style

Answer (score 0):

I added the form tag for inline forms, it works when you have enough room on the page for one line.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">

<p>My name is 
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" style='display:inline;'/>
from USA. And I'm     <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="21" class="form-control" style='display:inline;'/> years old.
</p>

</div>
</form>
```

Here's some more information explaining it from getbootstrap.com.

> "Add .form-inline to your  for left-aligned and inline-block controls. This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.
>
> Requires custom widths
>   Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form controls used within."

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Works in jsfiddle when it's wide enough.